# A simple list of unique values for a field with elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, json, elasticsearch

I need a simple list of unique values to build a filter option with.

My elasticsearch database has results that have a field like this:

```
country: [
    {
        value: "België",
        format: "plain_text"
    }
],
```

I need to generate a list of unique results from the country value. I don't need full results/hits with all the other info. A simple list of unique countries will suffice. Is there any functionality to do this with elasticsearch or am I forced to return full results and dig through them myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) like this:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "countries": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "country.value",
            "size": 100
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You can play with the `size` if you need more/less countries.

Comment: Thanks, I just found this in the documentation. It is a lot to read through since this is the first time I am using elasticsearch so I thought I would ask here. Thanks for helping out!